# Saving screenshot of a specific window as bmp in window

Tags: c++, windows

I need to get a screen view of a specific window as `.bmp` format. In other words I need to have the functionality of `alt+printscreen` and it needs to work even the window is at back or minimized. So I wrote a function below which returns a `HBITMAP` type in order to save the view as `.bmp` file with another function later.

```
HBITMAP CaptureWindowBitmap(HWND MyHWND)
{

HDC hWindowDC = GetWindowDC(MyHWND);     
HDC hMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hWindowDC);

int x = GetDeviceCaps(hWindowDC, HORZRES);
int y = GetDeviceCaps(hWindowDC, VERTRES);

HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hWindowDC, x, y);
HBITMAP hBitmapOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hBitmap);

BitBlt(hMemoryDC, 0, 0, x, y, hWindowDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
hBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hBitmapOld);

DeleteDC(hMemoryDC);
DeleteDC(hWindowDC);
return hBitmap;
}
```

However my function gets the image of the whole screen. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you validated that MyHWND is indeed the handle to the window you need to capture?  Did you use Spy++ or a similar tool to verify?

Comment: If the window is not in the foreground, or is partly covered by another window, or is minimised, there is no guarantee that it will have drawn to the DC that you're trying to copy from.

Comment: OK, I figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution i found from elsewhere:

```
HBITMAP CaptureWindowBitmap(HWND MyHWND)
{
RECT rc;
GetClientRect(MyHWND, &rc);

HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
HBITMAP hbmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);
SelectObject(hdc, hbmp);

PrintWindow(MyHWND, hdc, PW_CLIENTONLY);

DeleteDC(hdc);
ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);

return hbmp;
}
```

Window is captured by the function below:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
char buffer[128];
int written = GetWindowTextA(hwnd, buffer, 128);
if (written && strstr(buffer,WindowName) ) {
    *(HWND*)lParam = hwnd;
    return FALSE;
}
return TRUE;
}

HWND GetHwnd()
{
HWND hWnd = NULL;
EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, (LPARAM)&hWnd);
return hWnd;
}
```

where `LPCTSTR WindowName` is a global variable containing the name or partial name of the window.